# 2000 Hotsprings Sovereign Will not heat

Tags: hot-tub

My 2000 Hotsprings Sovereign will not heat at all.

Work Performed:

1. Installed all new filters.
2. Installed new 1.5kw/6kw replacement heater.
3. Unhooked all hoses to make sure of no air locks.
4. Circulation pump working properly with great flow coming from outlet in bottom of spa.
5. Jet pump works great.

Further troubleshooting performed:

1. Unhooked the heater from relay box and have 240 volts across both connections.
2. Check ohms on heater with a reading of 10.4 ohms. Heater checks OK.
3. Unhooked both thermistors with power off and T-Stat thermistor reads 9.9k Ohms and the Hi-limit thermistor reads 8.6K ohms.

I saw where ohms on thermistors should be around 10K. Higher if colder and lower if hotter. Ambient temp here today was 76 deg.

The Lowest digital reading on control panel is 80 deg. If I leave it at 80 the green light comes on "READY". When I turn it to 81 deg or higher, the light goes out. (it won't heat at all).

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what meter you are using, but I cannot think of one that wouldn't read above a few hundred k, or even MOhms. Look at the picture to the right, it probably says "K Ohms" or the scale you are on is 10k 10000, you're fine. From what you describe, it sounds like there is a lose connection (High resistance/open) in the system. From the heater unit back, check all molex connectors and wiirng, for anything melted, or oxidized. If everything up to the control panel looks good, visually inspect the control panel for same things, or water damage.

Comment: Well, I looked at everything and saw one of the jumpers on the relay box that feeds the heater wire was a little loose and had some burnt plastic on the wire connector so I made a new jumper with new connectors with proper gauge wire and VIOLA the heater is working. Unbelievable that's all it was hopefully. It was hidden and hard see with it being so close to the other jumpers. I did order new thermistors because they are cheap and have never been replaced since new in 2000. Thanks again for the reply and insight. Your suggestion of looking for electrical connections made me look harder at it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying the OP's comment which described the resolution as an answer:

> I looked at everything and saw one of the jumpers on the relay box
> that feeds the heater wire was a little loose and had some burnt
> plastic on the wire connector so I made a new jumper with new
> connectors with proper gauge wire and VIOLA the heater is working.
> Unbelievable that's all it was hopefully. It was hidden and hard see
> with it being so close to the other jumpers. I did order new
> thermistors because they are cheap and have never been replaced since
> new in 2000.
>
> Donnie Sharpless Sep 14 '17 at 22:19